# Going from MTB to CX - keep shoes?

Tags: mountain-bike, shoes, road

I am switching from a MTB (with pretty old, but still fine, SPD cleats) to a CX and am in the process of picking pedals. I won't be driving the MTB at all anymore, after that, and have switched it to non-cleat anyways, because I prefer it that way on slow, technical routes.

Do I want to worry about converting the shoes to the road cleat system? Or is that just a big hassle ending in an unhappy compromise? The point would be primarily to not have to go and look for new shoes (as the old ones are still well fitting and have not been used much), and just switch out the system.

Comment: Under what conditions are you going to be riding the CX bike? Road? Trails? Muddy trails? The answers are likely to be different. There's no rule that forbids SPDs on road; they're a good choice for commuting and touring, for example.

Comment: CX typically use mtn